# Midori prevents Facebook Log Out

Tags: midori

When using Midori I logged into my Facebook account once and am not unable to log out. This is because whenever I click the setting "cog" tab to access the "Sign Out" prompt Midori doesn't seem able to activate that drop down tab.

How might I *reset* Midori so that it drops this bad habit. Rebooting hasn't worked so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Midori is a simple browser designed to work well on lower powered(CPU/Memory) devices like the Pi. It does not stand up very well to JavaScript/CSS heavy web pages.

You can install Chromium the open source parts of Google's Chrome but it can be a bit heavy for the Pi, slowing everything else down.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

Your best be is to get the Raspberry Foundations own browser ...

http://www.raspberrypi.org/web-browser-beta/

but this is beta and comes with all the expected beta warnings.